# Write child batch files output to the log file created for parent batch file

Tags: batch-file

i have a batch file, b1.bat which internally starts another two batch files, b2.bat and b3.bat and b2.bat internall calls b4.bat and root batch file, b1.bat,waits until those three(b2,b3 and b4) finishes. In summary, scenario like this:

b1.bat -> b2.bat -> b4.bat 

           -> b3.bat

I want to write output of all 4 batch files(b1.bat, b2.bat, b3.bat and b4.bat) into single log file, my_log.txt. I want to do this with minimal effort ie., changing less no. of batch files as i have lot of batch files like this without logging. So i want to provide logging for them. 
I) Is it possible to control the log file output from parent batch file ie.,b1.bat?
II) Do i need to change all batch files with redirection operator which writes the output to log file?
I could'nt find proper solution for this. Please suggest me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are NOT doing any asynchronous processing using START, you should be able to simply use:

```
b1.bat >my_log.txt
```

You might also want to capture error messages by appending `2>&1` to the command.

Comment: I tried that one. But it is logging only b1.bat output but not writing the output of other batch files. :(

Comment: @Kaluva - b1 output is in the log, but b2,b3,b4 output is still on the screen/console? I'm not sure where you went wrong, because this should work. The command I gave must be issued from the command line or else from a new master batch file. You should not have to modify b1.bat at all. If it does not work for you, then your called batch files b2,b3,b4 must be directing their output to the console in a non-standard way. If you can't figure this out, you may have to post some of the failing code to let others help diagnose what is happening.